# Has any Stack Exchange site been closed after public beta?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, closed-sites

Going over the impressive list of topics discussed on the Stack Exchange network, it got me thinking - has there ever been a site that was in public beta, but then closed? Is there a list of these somewhere?

I assume sites in public beta are still being developed/grown - for example [CiviCRM.SE](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: According to [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aarea51.stackexchange.com+%22didn%27t+have+enough+activity+during+the+beta%22+-%22private%22), only two sites of Stack Exchange has ever been closed after reaching public beta. Many closed after private beta though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aarea51.stackexchange.com+"didn%27t+have+enough+activity+during+the+beta"+-"private"#q=site:area51.stackexchange.com+%22didn%27t+have+enough+activity+during+the+beta%22+-%22none%22) catches more sites that were closed after public beta. (~12 of them)

Comment: @ff524 awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information on failed beta site attempts is still available on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), including zipped dumps of their questions and answers.

However, as far as I know, there's no search mechanism to get a list of the closed sites.

To answer the question in the title - yes. Public betas also fail from time to time. For example, take a look at the now closed [Startup Business](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) site.